# LTspice XVII error. Cannot open file "...\schematic.op.raw" for output on simulation

Tags: ltspice, simulation

I just downloaded LTspice on Windows 11 and I'm having issues with running any simulation. I installed it to its default location as an administrator to be safe and whenever I open a file (e.g. audioamp.asc) and hit run, it tells me:

`Could not open file "C:\users\myUser\OneDrive\Documents\LTspiceXVII\examples\educational\audioamp.op.raw" for output`

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, as this is supposed to be a default example file.

Comment: Usually this message means that LTSpice or the user does not have write privileges. Try using C:\Users\<user>\Documents for your output files.

Comment: In the past I had similar issues when running files (not only LTspice files) that are located in a cloud-monitored directory (like OneDrive, Google Drive, Dropbox, ...).

Comment: It's the cloud that's the problem. You will find several topics on the [LTspice groups](https://groups.io.g.LTspice/) (registration needed, but free). If you only want to browse the topics, you don't have to register.

Comment: Looks like it runs into the same issue when the .asc file is under C:/Users/<user>/Documents. The error message reflects the change in location but is otherwise identical.

Comment: The cloud was the issue '..\Documents' was still being cloud monitored. When I moved it to 'D:\<folder name>\audioamp.asc' everything started working again. But I had to make the folder from scratch from the bottom level of the drive

Answer (score 1):

The cloud was the issue. 'C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents' and 'C:\Users\user\Documents' were both being cloud monitored. When I opened it from 'D:\New Folder\audioamp.asc' everything started working again.